# Why does my AngularJS code not bind to any variables?

Tags: angularjs

I have placed a simple fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/77vXu/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('test', function($scope) {
    $scope.cancelMessage = '';
    $scope.clickTest = function(){
        alert($scope.cancelMessage);
    };
};
```

and have tried to follow the basic tutorial as closely as possible. However, I can't get any of the variables to bind. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The end brackets for your controller needs to be this:

});

instead of this:

};

Answer (score 1):

I've update your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/77vXu/14/) to load Angular in the body and closed the controller as mentioned by user621545.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('test', function($scope) {
    $scope.cancelMessage = '';
    $scope.clickTest = function(){
        alert($scope.cancelMessage);
    }; 
});
```